# JavaFX only run with JDK

Tags: java, javafx

My JavaFX Desktop program only run with JDK 1.8 installed, doesnt run with JRE 1.8.

Any JavaFX Application should run with JRE?
If NO, How can I find why JDK is needed?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

This is because JavaFX runtime is not packaged into some distributions of JRE. As far as I know JavaFX will be in all distributions only when JDK 9 is released. Till then, it is safer to install JDK instead of JRE, or you can include `jfxrt.jar` when you export your project into JAR file.

Comment: JavaFX is included with Oracle JDK 8, with Oracle JDK 7 it was an optional installer. When using OpenJDK just installing OpenJFX should be sufficient. JDK is NOT required for JavaFX.

Comment: @FibreFoX My JRE (on my computer) 8u112 has no `jfxrt.jar`. It is still optional based on distribution.

Comment: what JRE do you use? Windows or Linux?

Comment: @FibreFoX Windows. Weird enough, I have other versions of JRE and they do have `jfxrt.jar`. JDK 8u122 has `jfxrt.jar`, though.

Comment: @FibreFoX, I compile the program with your gradle plugin, if I run the .jar file it runs with JRE 1.8, but the .exe gives an error or normally open if JDK is installed. Should be an error with your plugin?

Comment: @Marckaraujo that sounds strange, maybe there is something different thats odd. Heading to the github-project makes it possible to have better analyze ;) just make sure to put some project for recreating your issue

Comment: @FibreFoX, the problem is: With `JRE 1.8 X86` the application runs with `-jar` but not with `.exe`. With `JRE 1.8 X64` the application runs in both modes `-jar` and `.exe`. My system is Win 7 X64.

Comment: @Marckaraujo can you extend your SO-question with that detail? And how you are generating these, I think that details might be the source of your problems.

Comment: Issue for this on the project now: https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin/issues/67

Answer (score 0):

Per Oracle's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/installation/jfxpub-installation.htm), the JavaFX SDK and Runtime (`jfxrt.jar`) are included in the Java JDK, beginning with Java SE 7 Update 2. As long as the application was compiled with this version or later, it should run JavaFX.

Also per their [site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm), the JavaFX APIs are fully integrated with the Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE) and the Java Development Kit (JDK).

The specific location where you should find `jfxrt.jar` in both the JDK and JRE is:

- For Java 7, under [jre\lib](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html)
- For Java 8, under [jre\lib\ext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html)

Additional info can be found at Oracle's various JavaFX resources such as [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/) - though the latter was created for JavaFX 2, so may not be entirely compatible with the latest version of JavaFX.

Comment: Oracle also [mentioned](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html) that everything in `jre/lib/ext` are optional and vendor can exclude them at their discretion.

Comment: @Jai, but in this case I am using the official JRE 1.8, so all is included.